# Use a function within LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using LINQ to create a list.  But I want to use a function at the end to generate the object iself, something LINQ complains about

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'WashroomStatusItem GetWashroomStatusForItem(WashroomStatus)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
var query = (from c in context.WashroomStatus
    where c.WashroomId == GroupItem.WashroomID
    select GetWashroomStatusForItem(c));

private WashroomStatusItem GetWashroomStatusForItem(WashroomStatus item)
{
    WashroomStatusItem temp = new WashroomMonitorWCF.WashroomStatusItem();
    //do stuff with it
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving..

Comment: "something LINQ complains about" is far too vague. Please be more specific in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the SQL conversion can't convert your method into SQL. You should use `AsEnumerable()` to "switch" from the out-of-process provider to LINQ to Objects. For example:

```
var query = context.WashroomStatus
                   .Where(c => c.WashroomId == GroupItem.WashroomID)
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(c => GetWashroomStatusForItem(c));
```

Note that if `GetWashroomStatusForItem` only uses some properties, you may want to project to those separately first, to reduce the amount of information fetched from the server:

```
var query = context.WashroomStatus
                   .Where(c => c.WashroomId == GroupItem.WashroomID)
                   .Select(c => new { c.Location, c.Date };
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(p => GetWashroomStatusForItem(p.Location, p.Date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's answer is correct, but I'd add that depending on the nature of `GetWashroomStatusForItem()`, it should probably either be broken down into LINQ statements and added into the query itself, or it should be executed after the query has returned.

So, lets say `GetWashroomStatusForItem()` looks something like this: note that this is extremely oversimplified.

```
public static WashroomStatus GetWashroomStatusForItem(Item c)
{
    return c.WashroomStatus;
}
```

it should just be added to the LINQ query like this:

```
var query = (from c in context.WashroomStatus
    where c.WashroomId == GroupItem.WashroomID
    select c.WashroomStatus);
```

But if it relies heavily on stuff not in the db, I'd just end the Linq statement before you get the `WashroomStatus`, and then call `GetWashroomStatusForItem()` on the results. It's not gonna a performance difference since Linq uses lazy evaluation, and you *generally* want to keep db operations separate from "programmatic" ones.